# Basic audio amplifer circuit with transistors

Tags: transistors, amplifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple Audio amplifier Using Transistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25748/simple-audio-amplifier-using-transistors)

I'm looking for a basic audio amplifier(1w - 0.5w) circuit which is designed with transistors. Could you help about that?