# Convert a [0,5]V wave to [-2,2]V wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, speakers, voltage-reference

Using a PIC, I got a signal oscillating around 2.5V +-[0,2.5]V approximately. This is intended to generate a simple sound through a small speaker.

The speaker, unfortunately works with 0V +-[0,2]V, and I expect the direct usage of 0-5V not resulting in the same sound (or even breaking the speaker). Consequently, I would need to displace the ground to 2.5 for the speaker.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuxmgf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Could someone indicate me the direction for a solution?**

---

Current status:

I did not managed to go very far,

- Using opamp, but they mostly threat the input voltage, so a negative voltage source is required. I should probably reminder how they work in case it is the solution.
- Splitting the voltage with resistors, but that did not convinced me due to attenuation.
- I finally looked for some LM317 to generate a ground at 2.5V; However, I am not sure if it would work when the wave provide "negative" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYRh7m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use an LM4865
[image]

Comment: Nice circuit! Is the BC547B/BC557B adequate for this circuit?

Comment: If OA delivers 10mA then for 4V into 4 Ohms or 1000mA then a  gain of >>100 is marginally OK with those

Comment: It seem to me that U2 on your diagram goes saturated (The positive wave is cut at the top. To solve it, I added a resistor to ground from the + input of U2. Could you check/confirm it please?

Comment: There will be saturation in both NPN and PNP drivers that cannot be avoided as well as the Op Amp of choice. Using two in differential extends the power to one output.

Comment: ... unless very low RdsOn MOSFETs are used. Then crossover +-Vgs must be controlled with a deadband that is quickly passed thru. In Motor bridges the deadband is saturated and defined by dead-time in us.

Comment: BC547B/BC557B are inadequate 0.1A and 60mW max

Answer (score 3):

Place a capacitor in series with your signal to remove the DC offset. Maybe 10µF non-polarised. You can then use a voltage divider (or potentiometer) as an attenuator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1h1m9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that driving a speaker direct is not recommended (and may not even work properly). Instead you should use some form of power amplifier to provide the current the speaker needs.

Comment: Beat me by 19 seconds!

Comment: :P I draw faster ;)

Comment: It will be now difficult to choose a "winner" :-D

Comment: Just curious - any particular reason for using a non-polarised cap as there seems to be DC bias across it?

Comment: @JImDearden Because there is AC going *through* it. Once you remove the DC bias you are left with AC which has no polarity.

Comment: @JImDearden - It is fine to use a nonpolarized capacitor with DC bias across it. Polarized capacitors are not mandatory when there is DC across them, but they must be installed in the correct orientation if used.

Comment: But surely its the same for any decoupling capacitor with AC through it where you have a more positive voltage on one plate - on the input side the average voltage is +2.5V ( 0 - 5V) and on the other plate its 0V (-2.5V to +2.5V) since the average of an AC signal is 0.

Comment: @JImDearden No, it's not the same. In decoupling the - is connected direct to ground. In DC offset removal one side is the signal and the other is connected to the load. The load side can swing + and -. In decoupling the "load" side is always 0V and the "signal" side is always positive.

Comment: @vofa I agree a non polarised  cap will do, but its a lot cheaper to use a polarised (at larger uF values) unless there is some technical reason to do so and I don't see it.

Comment: @JImDearden - There is no technical reason to use a non-polarized capacitor in this circuit. As long as the bias polarity is reliable, a polarized capacitor will work, cost less, and will probably perform better.

Comment: @vofa That's exactly the point I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 2):

Your output signal is 0-5V, or 2.5VDC +/- 2.5VAC.

You can remove the DC content of a signal by passing it through an AC coupling capacitor. You can attenuate by using a voltage divider. The size of these components will depend on the frequency response desired. C1 will tend to be large (in the uF range). This tool can help you size the components: http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRhikeisan.htm

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlByj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you're just making "beep" sounds, there's no need to use a fancy circuit.

The easiest to use are the piezoelectric transducers. You can probably drive it directly with the PIC digital output pin, or user 1 transistor at the most. Take a look at the datasheet for this part I randomly picked.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tdk-corporation/PS1240P02BT/445-2525-3-ND/935924

Piezoelectric transducers are resonant at high frequency so you'll need to use several kHz.

If you want to drive a real speaker and just make beeps but at wide frequency range, then you can just use a simple push-pull circuit with a large coupling cap.

[image: Push-pull schematic]

The simulation shows the circuit driving roughly 180 milliWatts into an 8 Ohm speaker at 500 Hz. I hope that helps. -Vince

Answer (score 1):

There are so many circuits to drive a speaker. 
The link [here](https://developer.mbed.org/users/4180_1/notebook/using-a-speaker-for-audio-output/) describes multiple ways of achieving your goal.

LM386 is widely used as an audio amplifier in hobby projects and interfacing circuits are easily available.

Depending on the power output requirement, suitable audio amplifier can be chosen. The LM386 can easily drive a 8 ohm speaker. The gain can be adjusted easily by proper biasing.

Another bunch of good solutions are [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/25748/76537).